# Помогите с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

В потоке данных мне надо найти все совпадения со словом "Призрачный Удар",кроме вот таких выражений (03:24 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для Саргон).

```
03:08 Кроличья лапка, подкова в перчатке и прием "Призрачный Удар" помогли vikawin продержаться ещё немного. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:10 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для vikawin
03:24 Саргон, нетрезво оценив положение, решил, что его спасение это прием "Призрачный Удар". (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:24 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для Саргон
03:24 Саргон, нетрезво оценив положение, решил, что его спасение это прием "Призрачный Удар". (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:25 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для Саргон
03:27 Саргон, нетрезво оценив положение, решил, что его спасение это прием "Призрачный Удар". (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:28 don_karlion, понял, пропустив очередной удар в голову, что поможет ему только прием "Призрачный Удар". (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:28 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для Саргон
03:28 Кроличья лапка, подкова в перчатке и прием "Призрачный Удар" помогли spiritdevil продержаться ещё немного. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:29 ФИНТ, пораскинув мозгами по земле, сообразил, что его выручат или прием "Призрачный Удар" или вмешательство Мусорщика. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:29 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для don_karlion
03:29 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для ФИНТ
03:30 Алекс Е-бург, пораскинув мозгами по земле, сообразил, что его выручат или прием "Призрачный Удар" или вмешательство Мусорщика. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:31 Кроличья лапка, подкова в перчатке и прием "Призрачный Удар" помогли don_karlion продержаться ещё немного. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:31 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для spiritdevil
03:32 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для don_karlion
03:32 Кроличья лапка, подкова в перчатке и прием "Призрачный Удар" помогли ФИНТ продержаться ещё немного. (Защита от дробящего урона (%): +50)
03:33 Закончилось действие эффекта "Призрачный Удар" для Алекс Е-бург
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот таким выражением

```
/(?<!Закончилось действие эффекта) ("Призрачный Удар")/
```

первые скобки проверяют, что заданного в них выражения нет в строке. Вторые скобки проверяют, что заданная строка есть. Для тестов можете использовать сервис [regex101](http://regex101.com/). NB! используются PCRE!.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за сервис) Хоть регулярками пользуюсь редко, но он явно будет полезен)

Comment: Ну я обычно пользуюсь вот этим http://php-include.ru/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-onlain

Comment: я попробовал там пару выражений... как то оно странно работает. К тому же, самое главное - совсем не понятно, какое подмножество он поддерживает.